# ffplay displays runtime error, yet still plays file

Tags: python, python-2.7, ffmpeg, pydub

Im Working with pydub, and I'm using ffplay.  For some reason, when the program runs i get this 'error':

```
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydub/utils.py:178: 

RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffplay or avplay - defaulting to ffplay, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffplay or avplay - defaulting to ffplay, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
```

However, it still plays the selected audio file.

1. Is there a way to make this warning disappear, as it happens every time i play it?
2. If i can't, is there anyway i can configure this so that it uses pyaudio to play the stream?

Answer (score 0):

It's a warning (and not an error) because it's possible that everything is fine, but that is not guaranteed.

The warning is displayed when you import `pydub.playback` (which, in retrospect wasn't the best place for it).

That said, you'll probably want to use pyaudio directly for all but the very simplest cases. Pydub's [pyaudio playback code](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/playback.py#L23) provides a starting point if you like (inlined below for posterity):

```
def play_with_pyaudio(seg):
    """
    seg should be a pydub.AudioSegment instance
    """
    import pyaudio

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(seg.sample_width),  
                    channels=seg.channels,
                    rate=seg.frame_rate,
                    output=True)

    # break audio into half-second chunks (to allows keyboard interrupts)
    for chunk in make_chunks(seg, 500):
        stream.write(chunk._data)

    stream.stop_stream()  
    stream.close()  

    p.terminate()
```